# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition' in Windows

Tags: python, pycharm, speech-recognition

I'm getting an Error on Speech Recognition.

I Just Typed 1 line of Code:-

```
import speech_recognition
```

& I'm getting a Following Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        import speech_recognition
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

I've Tried Installing Speech Recognition Package Through Terminal & Also Inside Settings-Project-Python Interpreter-Packages.

Comment: The question needs to describe _how_ you installed the module, and also any steps you took to ensure that the specific interpreter or virtualenv you installed it into is the same one that can't find it now.

Comment: I've Tried Installing Speech Recognition Package Through Terminal & Also Inside Settings-Project-Python Interpreter-Packages. & I'm Using the Same Virtualenv

Comment: There is nothing more we can tell you here except: make sure you installed properly and to the appropriate version of Python you are using